# Zero article in front of ''typical"

Tags: articles

Why is there no article in front of "typical"?

> They met one evening in typical New York fashion at a gallery opening

Source: [Sex and the City Season 1 Episode 1 (Transcript)](https://www.satctranscripts.com/2008/08/sex-and-city-season-1-episode-1.html#.W5aHyOgzbIV)

Answer (score 3):

There, **fashion** means "mode, style, manner". The reference is not to a particular instance of New York fashion but to New York fashion itself, as a mode. When the noun phrase refers to a mode,  no article is necessary, and if one is used, it is the definite article.

> He likes his BBQ prepared in Kansas City style.
>
> He likes his BBQ prepared in the Kansas City style.

or

> Put your Bluetooth-capable mobile phone in pairing mode.

or

> They stood **in silence**.

The reference is not to a particular silence but to silence as mode of being or behavior, as manner. They stood *silently*.